How do I interpret the discrete Laplacian being an approximation of the Hessian (Force Constant) matrix?
Mathematically, the discrete Laplacian is equivalent to the trace of the Hessian. I've read in my literature review that the Force Constant Matrix (FCM) of a lattice system, which is a Hessian matrix, may be approximated by the discrete Laplacian due to this equivalence. However, It's unclear whether this is simply a mathematical trick or if there exists a physical interpretation of the approximation. In other words, what are the required constraints (if any) on the lattice system for the discrete Laplacian to approximately represent the phonon dynamics of a crystal lattice?
Edit: Here is a Phys.Rev.B article that uses the discrete Laplacian to propose a Discrete Laplacian Thermostat where a good amount of the physics is discussed, but is a bit dense. Another reference is Large-Scale Phonon Calculations Using the Real-Space Multigrid Method published in JCTC, which relates it to the Force Constant Matrix.

Please give the exact reference: title, authors, chapter/section, page number; and a link if possible.

@6D-Hyper-Sphere please edit this into the post, rather than leaving it as a comment (which is deletable).

There is no article cited here.

I've fixed the links. Please, let me know if you can provide any insight.
